# Annexed submodules in git

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-annex

I'd like to keep some binary files (documentation, executable binary files, images, etc) in a `git-annex`, and then include them in several projects as `git-submodules`. I think this will allow me to keep track of the correct versions of these large files as they change, keeping old projects linked to the old versions and new projects to the new versions.

So I make the following repo for my big files:

```
mkdir annexedrepo
cd annexedrepo
cp big_files annexedrepo/
git init
git annex init
git annex add .
```

and then go to my project repo and add them as a submodule.

```
cd ../otherrepo
mkdir data
git submodule add ../annexedrepo data/annexed
```

I'd love if these would just appear as symlinks to the correct files in the other repo. But I guess it's good enough if I can just make the copies as I need them with:

```
git annex get data/annexed
```

This copies the files over - I can see them in `otherrepo/.git/module/data/annexed/objects/`. But when I do this, the annexed files are just dead symlinks. I can list them with `ls data/annexed/`, but nobody's home.

Am I trying to do something wrongheaded? Is there a way to fix this? Are these bugs in either `git-submodule` or `git-annex`? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the same source tree structure and also tried to use `git-annex` but met the same problem. I found out the `git-fat` extension can be used instead of `git-annex` and has no such an issue. So my source tree looks like this:

```
/project
    .git
    .gitmodules
    ...
    <project files and folders>
    ...
    submodule
        .git
        .gitattributes
        .gitfat
        ...
        <binary files>
        ...
```

To clone such a project

```
git clone git://... project
cd project
git submodule init
git submodule update
cd submodule
git fat init
git fat pull
```

The `git-fat` uses `rsync` to push/pull files. [See more about git-fat](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat).

Answer (score 3):

Well, with a bit of fiddling, I've found a work-around. I'd love to see something better, though. Posting this for posterity, but I'm hoping to find a better solution.

In `data/annexed`, there is a file, `.git`, which contains a reference to `../../.git/module/data/annexed/`. I removed this file and replaced it with a symlink to the same location. I now have access to `../annexedrepo/` from inside `data/annexed`, and my files are at the right version. I'm a bit worried about causing future problems with this workaround...